# Why is my Workbook_BeforeSave preventing my Workbook_AfterSave to run

Tags: excel, vba

I have come across similar problems where the AfterSave wont run for people but their answers havent dealt with my situation where it seems the reason for my AfterSave not running is my BeforeSave code. Both these sets of code work properly independently of each other but I cant get them to run in the same workbook.

The code is currently written in "ThisWorkbook" and simply sets the save name of a file to a cell value before saving and then after saving it is to update a text file by adding 1 to the number in the text file.

From my research it seems the problem has to do with either the `Cancel` or the `Application.EnableEvents`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim sFile As String
    sFile = Range("B3").Value & ".xlsm"
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show sFile
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF
    'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(arg1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
Application.EnableEvents = True
If Success Then
 'Open the text file to overwrite the number in the text file
 Open "\\digitalsense.com.au\FileShares\Public\_Purchase Orders\PO_Number_Generator.txt" For Output As #1
 'Overwrite the number with the PO number
 Print #1, Cells(1, 2)
 'Close the text file
 Close #1
End If
End Sub
```

I should be able to click on save or save as per normal and the file name field is pre-populated with the text in cell `B3`. After saving my text file needs to be updated by incrementing the number in the text file by 1.

Comment: If you set Cancel to `True` then the save is cancelled...

Comment: Why don't you check if SaveAsUI is True and exit the _BeforeSave event? While trying to reproduce your issue my Excel crashed multiple times when I made unsaved changes in the original workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `BeforeSave` you're setting `Cancel = True` - this has the effect of cancelling the Save operation, so there's no `AfterSave` event fired.

EDIT:  maybe something like this

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sFile As String
    sFile = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value & ".xlsm"

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'did the file get saved?
    If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(sFile) Then
        UpdateSequenceNumber ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Cancel = True
End Sub


Sub UpdateSequenceNumber(newVal)
    Open "\\digitalsense.com.au\FileShares\Public\_Purchase Orders\PO_Number_Generator.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, newVal
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but the reason I did that was if I don't set Cancel = True then when I click save or save as it has the save box pop up twice. So ill click saveas and save the workbook and as i do that a second save dialogue box will appear and I have to re do it. How can I avoid the double save and also get the AfterSave to work?

Comment: If you want `Workbook_AfterSave` to run you can call it directly.

Comment: Hi Tim. Any chance you can help me code that based on my code please?

Comment: I really can't tell exactly what it is you're trying to make happen - the code for your beforeSave doesn't seem to match the description of what you want to do.

Comment: Im trying to get the code to save my workbook as the text in cell B3 as a macro enabled excel file and also as a pdf (which it does but it does it twice). After it has done that my AfterSave event needs to increment the number in my my text file number by 1. It must only perform the increment once though and only after the workbook has been saved - in other words confirming that the number has been used. This is done so that the next time someone uses this workbook they will generate a number that is next in line (this is done using a button and macro elsewhere on the workbook).

Comment: Does B3 contain the full path, or just the fileName? How is the initial save action triggered?  From a button/code or via the regular "Save" menu/ribbon ?

Comment: B3 only contains the fileName. The user can still select the directory/path and this is triggered via the regular "Save" menu/button. Im trying to keep it uncomplicated after having a save button originally. Its a lot less confusing for the user if they can follow their normal steps to save.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim sFile As String
sFile = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value & ".xlsm"Application.EnableEvents = False
'did the file get saved?
If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(sFile) Then
    UpdateSequenceNumber ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Cancel = True End SubSub UpdateSequenceNumber(newVal)
Open "\\digitalsense.com.au\FileShares\Public\_Purchase Orders\PO_Number_Generator.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, newVal
Close #1
```

End Sub